# Cross Validation - Scaler Method not Being Applied in a Pipeline

Tags: scikit-learn, pipeline, cross-validation

I have an issue when doing some cross validation using Scikit Learn.
I have build a pipeline consisting of 2 elements: a scaler and a regression model.

My issue is that I found out that the scaler method that I had configured in the pipeline was not applied (i.e.; taken into account) during the calculations.

Please, check my notebook and tell what is wrong.
Here's the link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KHqHsDHNkGLj4e0u-EWY9oj00NXeO5u3?usp=sharing

And here's also the link to the dataset that I have used:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nyx0BitzxBLQjsAAAxfHt-9SzKqk9dWv/view?usp=sharing

Best regards.

Comment: Please paste code (of a minimal reproducible example) into the question body.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The code is full, well detailed and anyone can reproduce the problem. In addition, my concern is well explained.

Answer (score 1):

The scaler is being applied.  Scaling has no effect on an unpenalized linear regression, and so it is expected that the cross-validation scores would be the same.  Compare with `Lasso`, where scaling does matter.

Comment: Ben. To show you the difference, I have scaled my data then configured a new pipeline (that's pipeline2). The score that I have obtained at last is totally different from the initial one (check the notebook again). What was the issue with my first pipeline?

Comment: In the new approach you scale the `y` values as well (which doesn't happen in the pipeline approach). The resulting model still captures the same relationship, but the metric is scaled accordingly.

Comment: I can't understand why "y" doesn't need to to be scaled as opposed to x. Anyway, what's wrong with my coding approach, my pipelines, my metrics. Could you please do some changes to the notebook so that I can see the good approach and best practice.